# Как работают с исключениями и блоком try catch

Tags: c++, исключения, try-catch

Вот есть блок try catch, в нём можно обрабатывать исключения. **А как им корректно пользоваться?**
Если мы обрабатываем какие-то данные в `try{обработка данных}`, то при каком-то некорректном поведении мы попадаем в блок `catch(...){данные об ошибке и их обработка}`. Тут всё, кажется, просто и понятно. Но как же этим пользоваться в больших проектах, где все дальнейшие строки кода зависят от результата обработки в этом try catch?

Вот небольшой *тривиальный* *пример*, который мне пришёл в голову. **Корректна ли в общем такая архитектура?**

```
bool DIV(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) throw 1;
    int c = a / b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    bool Continue = true;
    int a, b;   
    while (Continue) 
    {
        try
        {
            std::cin >> a;
            std::cin >> b;
            Continue = DIV(a, b);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Next:" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Конечно лучше указать в обьявлении функции список исключений.   Как  не упускать обработку исключений?.. Не думаю, что ответ однозначен: очень по разному.     Посмотрим кто даст исчерпающий ответ.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan что Вы имеете в виду под указанием в объявлении ф-и списка исключений? Вы про void funct() throw(AnyError) {...} ?

Comment: Польза от исключений приходит когда ошибку приходится пробрасывать через длинную цепочку вызовов. А в данном случае у вас положительный результат возвращается в виде кода ошибки, а отрицательный - в виде исключения. Это тот пример как раз иллюстрирует крайне плохую ситуацию для использования исключения - функция по прежнему возвращает код ошибки но при этом исключения обрабатываются там же, где и код ошибки. Короче говоря, максимальный оверхед.

Comment: Также стоит отметить, что потенциальная польза от исключений часто нивелируется сложностью написания кода корректного по отношению к исключениям при отсутствии адекватной помощи со стороны компилятора. В свете новых стандартов, полностью убравших (вместо усиления) минимальный контроль исключений, существовавший ранее, эта проблема становится особенно острой.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, синтаксис `throw(type1, type2, ...)` признан устаревшим в C++11 и полностью удален из языка в C++17. Не советуйте писать некорректный код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключения позволяют отложить обработку возникшей ошибки (исключительной ситуации) до момента, когда будет ясно как эту ошибку обработать. При этом по умолчанию (т.е. без какого-либо обработчика) ошибка не может быть просто проигнорирована, как это можно было бы делать со всевозможными кодами возвратов из функций или вариациями глобальной переменной `errno`. Если исключение вывалится на глобальный уровень, произойдёт аварийное завершение программы (вызовется `std::terminate`).

Если есть вся необходимая информация что делать с ошибкой по месту её проверки, то более правильным вариантом остаётся обычный `if` без каких-либо исключений вовсе. Но если есть какая-то, возможно, довольно длинная цепочка вложенных вызовов и проблема возникает далеко внутри от внешнего кода, который может, например, выполнить вывод диагностического сообщения пользователю в графическом интерфейсе, или записать в лог, или сделать что-то ещё, о чём не может даже догадываться разработчик функции, в которой может произойти какая-то критическая ошибка, то исключениям тут самое место.

Comment: Ответ конечно полезный, но не понел какая часть отвечает на  вопрос:  "как пользоваться  этим   в больших проектах"?    Мне показалось имеется ввиду как узнать когда какое исключение нужно пытаться ловить?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ловить нужно те исключения, которые пользователю кода (библиотеки) понятно как обработать. Конкретный перечень типов исключений, которые может породить тот или иной библиотечный код, должен быть опубликован автором библиотеки.

Comment: согласен, но вот вы пишете большой проект, используя там  тысяча функций и обьектов.  Как проследить, где  не поймано исключение, где упустили ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если упустили - приложение крешнется